# Error while Initializating Fabric-CA server

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, certificate-authority, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I am trying to initialize fabric-ca following its [user guide](https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users-guide.html#fabric-ca-server) using [this](https://pastebin.com/aZfsvYYp) config file but when executing the following command:

```
fabric-ca-server init --cafiles fabric-ca-server-config.yaml
```

I am getting the following error:

```
2018/11/12 22:59:45 [DEBUG] Intializing nonce manager for issuer 'undercroft'
2018/11/12 22:59:45 [DEBUG] Closing server DBs
2018/11/12 22:59:45 [FATAL] Initialization failure: CA name 'undercroft' is used in '/home/paradox/hyperledger/fabric/undercroft/fabric-ca/server/fabric-ca-server-config.yaml' and '/home/paradox/hyperledger/fabric/undercroft/fabric-ca/server/fabric-ca-server-config.yaml'
```

While I am getting this error if I am using the command line flags of `fabric-ca-server` I am successfully able to initialize and launch the

[This](https://pastebin.com/VnpzA7VE) is the full error log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now the `--cafiles` flag is only used when there are multiple CAs, in case of a single ca it will only use the config file at the `$FABRIC_CA_SERVER_HOME` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try if you change the CN of the fabric-ca-server ? or change the name of the CA ?

Comment: Yes I did but with no success.